# Android not sending proper keyCode on text input

Tags: javascript, android, mobile-chrome, gboard

I want to capture the keydown-event for a specific key (<) for all elements in a website. On Windows and iOS this is not a problem and everything is working fine. On Android (OnePlus 6, Android 10, Chrome 81, Gboard-Keyboard) however I couldnt manage to get the proper keyCode for the pressed key, therefore resulting in a essential function of my site not working. The keyCode always shows up as unidentified, 0 or 226.

What i am trying to accomplish:

1. Focus any kind of element on the page
2. Press <-key
3. Focus a certain input as soon as the <-key was pressed

The code that is working on Windows and iOS:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.key === "<") {
    $("#text2").focus();
  } else {
    // this is just for testing purposes
    alert(e.key);
  }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/rv6tc5mj/15/

What I´ve tried so far:

1. switching from keydown to keyup, keypress - keyup doesnt change anything, keypress doesnt trigger on Android
2. using another keyboard - no success
3. using e.keyCode, e.which, e.charCode - no success

As it seems, this issue is known but these workarounds dont work in my case since i need to catch the keydown-event everywhere, not just in a single input.

Do you have any ideas or workarounds? Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.